# The server 127.0.0.1:3128 requires a username and password. The server says : cntlm for parent

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, ntlm

I have just installed cntlm on my new Ubuntu 12.04. In configuration file `etc/cntlm.conf`, I inserted my network configure like below:

```
Username: myUsername
Domain : myDomain
Password: myPassword

Proxy : myProxy:8080

Listen: 3128
```

But when I set `127.0.0.1:3128` as my browser network proxy and when I want to visit a website, the pop up menu of cntlm appeared and wants the username and password.

What is the solution to this? How can I get my network domain name? I think my domain name or other particulars may be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

1) Install CNTLM to default directory (on Windows, C:\Program Files (x86)\cntlm\ ).

2) Run **cmd.exe**

3) Type : **cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\cntlm\"**

4) Type : **cntlm.exe -H -d your_domain -u your_username**

It will ask your password. Enter your password and cntlm will give you some hashes.
Something like this:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm>cntlm -H -d your_domain -u your_username
Password:
PassLM          4E9C185900C7CF0B6FFCB2044F81920C
PassNT          6E9F120B83EEA0E875CE8E6F9730EC9A
PassNTLMv2      2A0B7C2457FB7DD8DA4EB737C4FA224F
```

Now you have password hashed. Save them to a text editor.

5) Type : **cntlm -M http://www.google.com**

Again enter your password.
It will give you something like that

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Cntlm>cntlm -M http://www.google.com
Password:
Config profile  1/4... Credentials rejected
Config profile  2/4... OK (HTTP code: 302)
----------------------------[ Profile  1 ]------
Auth            NTLM
PassNT          6E9F120B83EEA0E875CE8E6F9730EC9A
PassLM          4E9C185900C7CF0B6FFCB2044F81920C
------------------------------------------------
```

Now you see that profile 2 is successful. Because it says OK for profile 2. It may be different on you system.

The trick is,

- if the Auth is NT, then you must use only PassNT
- if the Auth is LM, then you must use only PassLM
- if the Auth is NTLM, then you must use both PassLM and PassNT
- if the Auth is NTLMv2, then you must use only PassNTLMv2

Now we got all we want.
For my configuration, Auth says NTLM so I will use both PassNT and PassLM in the cntlm.ini configuration file.

This is an example configuration file according to given answers:

```
#
# Cntlm Authentication Proxy Configuration File
#

Username yourusername
Domain yourdomain

Auth NTLM
PassNT 6E9F120B83EEA0E875CE8E6F9730EC9A
PassLM 4E9C185900C7CF0B6FFCB2044F81920C

Workstation yourhostname.yourdomain

# Most probably proxy.yourdomain:8080
Proxy  yourProxyIP:yourProxyPort

NoProxy  localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*

Listen  3132

Gateway yes
```

Now you can use your computer's IP address and port 3132 as a proxy.

Note 1: Don't use domain\username as username
Note 2: If there is any then don't forget to use '.intra' extension after your domain (yourdomain.intra)

Comment: Very informative. Thank you! Well, there in only one thing - question has "ubuntu" tag. But I guess having answer for windows will not hurt since someone probably will have same issue with Windows.

Comment: Ops! I have missed that tag but anyway, the installing to the default directory is mandatory for Windows since there is a bug related to that.

Comment: Great !! Thanks to your answer I was able to connect my Ubuntu VirtualBox VM to internet through my corporate proxy

Answer (score 2):

In the `cntlm.conf` file, be sure to substitute the field `Password` with one of the following fields:

- `PassLM` (if you use LM hash)
- `PassNT` (if you use NT hash)
- `PassNTLMv2` (if you use NTLMv2 hash)

Then, you should not write the plain text password, but the corresponding hash, which can be computed with `cntlm -H -d <domain> -u <user>`

Comment: cntlm -H -d <domain> -u <user> works great!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.

First of all, try this command:

```
sudo cntlm -M http://www.google.com
```

See the results. If the only method **OK** is **Auth = LM**, then you need to modify the configuration file on (uncomment this lines):

```
Auth         LM
Flags        0x06820000
```

If you don't know how to change the configuration file, make this:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/cntlm.conf
```

Remember to restart the CNTLM:

```
sudo service cntlm restart
```

Comment: Config profile  1/4... Credentials rejected
Config profile  2/4... Credentials rejected
Config profile  3/4... Credentials rejected
Config profile  4/4... Credentials rejected

Wrong credentials, invalid URL or proxy doesn't support NTLM nor BASIC.

Comment: I'm not a network administrator,but I use Nautilus (file manager) to check the Domain that my PC is connected. See this [image](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/images/samba-nautilus-domain.png). Opening the "Windows Network" you can verify the list of Domains available.